# Is it an anti pattern to dispatch actions from an action file that are subscribed to from a different reducer file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

Usually in my Redux projects I have action and reducer files that come in pairs. So in my `actions` folder I will have a `posts.js` and in my `reducers` folder I will also have a `posts.js`. The posts action file usually just dispatch action types that are subscribed to in the posts reducer file.

But now I need to dispatch an action type from the `posts` action file that is subscribed to from the `authors` reducer file. Is this okay or considered an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't anti-pattern at all. It's good code-reusability and especially useful for error-handling.

Consider the following example:

### posts.js

```
import { GET_POSTS } from "./actions/types"
import { setErrors } from "./actions/errors"
import axios from "axios"

export const getPosts = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       axios.get("/api/posts")
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                   type: GET_POSTS,
                   payload: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch((errors) => {
                dispatch(setErrors(errors.response.data))
            }
   }
}
```

### errors.js

```
const setErrors = (errors) => {
   return {
      type: SET_ERRORS,
      payload: errors
   }
}
```

So instead of defining a completely new post-related **errors** action inside **posts.js**, it makes sense to just import an existing one that is subscribed to your errors-reducer (if any). The same could be said about using your **author** and **post** actions together.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! I noticed in your example you also import `setErrors` function from another action file although in the example you don't use it. Generally is that an anti-pattern to call an action function from another file's action function or no?

Comment: @TK123 You're welcome! And no, it would not be anti-pattern. Let me update my solution to paint the picture a bit more clearly. I was lost in my train of thought and forgot that I even imported setErrors haha.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which design pattern you are following.
As you may have all your actions in a single file.
For your case you can export the action creator from one file and just import it where you want same action creator.
This way you can have the same syncing between action creators and reducers as you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not following the pattern where the action types are in the same file as the reducer (I think the ducks pattern does this). I have my action types in a separate file and I import them them in my action and reducer files. From a technical standpoint I can do what I'm asking for and it works. Just not sure if it's an anti-pattern or not.

Comment: I am not talking about the action types i am talking about the action creators which returns the action to dispatch